# Using grid_extra after looping with ggplot2

Tags: r

I am have to run many ggplots on my data and so am trying to loop through variables. I would like to place the plots in a grid arrangement using grid_extra. I have managed to write code for the loop in order to create the plots for my list but am unsure how to extend that to grid extra. Here is my code:

```
data("mtcars")
mtcars$gear=as.factor(mtcars$gear)

lflist=list("mpg", "hp", "drat", "wt")
lfplot=list()
for(i in seq_along(lflist)) {
  lfplot=ggplot(data=subset(mtcars, !is.na(gear)), aes(x=gear, 
  y=lflist[i]))+geom_boxplot()+
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", aes(group=1), colour="red")+
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="point", colour="red")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=8),axis.title.x = element_blank())

}
```

Comment: I get an error when trying to plot one of them: `Error: stat_boxplot requires the following missing aesthetics: y` Where do you define `y`? Before making a list of plot, are you sure that you can plot each of them?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I defined my y in `lflist` - these are the variables I am looping over. I re-ran the code and didn't get an error.

Comment: I think @Masoud is right. I had to modify your code using `aes_string`, as shown below.

Comment: @Lyngbakr I would also add `as.character(lflist[i])` to be sure that it will work with all versions of `ggplot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. We also added some hints in the inline comments. Let us know if anything is unclear for you.

```
library(ggplot2)

data("mtcars")
mtcars$gear=as.factor(mtcars$gear)

# In such simple cases, it is advisable to use vectors rather than list
# lflist = list("mpg", "hp", "drat", "wt") 
lflist = c("mpg", "hp", "drat", "wt")
lfplots = list()

for(i in seq_along(lflist)) { # Hint, you can loop directry over the entries (for element in lflist)
  # Create your plot
  lfplot = ggplot(data=subset(mtcars, !is.na(gear)), aes(x=gear, y=lflist[i])) + 
    geom_boxplot()+
    stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", aes(group=1), colour="red") +
    stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="point", colour="red") +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=8),
          axis.title.x = element_blank())

  # Add your plot to the list
  lfplots[[length(lfplots) + 1]] = lfplot
}


library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(grobs = lfplots, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `cowplot`.

```
data("mtcars")
mtcars$gear=as.factor(mtcars$gear)

lflist=list("mpg", "hp", "drat", "wt")
lfplot=list()
for(i in seq_along(lflist)) {
    lfplot[[i]] <- ggplot(data=subset(mtcars, !is.na(gear)), aes_string(x="gear",y=lflist[[i]])) + geom_boxplot() +
    stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", aes(group=1), colour="red")+
    stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="point", colour="red")+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=8),axis.title.x = element_blank())
}

library(cowplot)

plot_grid(plotlist = lfplot)
```

[image]